# Dial Meter using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on Data Logging Software using python. I can draw the graph based on the real time quantity but I want to create a Dial meter to show the real time values using Tkinter.Is it possible to create a dial meter and rotate the dial with respect to real time dynamic data ?

Comment: Here is a canvas dial widget for tkinter: [TkDial](https://github.com/Akascape/TkDial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no dial widgets built into Tkinter. However, there is a canvas on which you can draw. A dial isn't much more than a circle with an arrow pointing a particular direction. A little math is all you need to decide where to draw the dial.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I got the range of 0 to 200 and want to divide it in the step of 10. Could you tell me how will place those steps on semicircle and rotate the dial respectively.